# In which nuget package is IApplicationBuilder extension UseEndpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a middleware library and want to include routing, so have added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` but the `UseEndpoints` extension isn't available. If I add the mega package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` then it's fine, but I don't want to include all the things. Thanks!

Comment: namespace (Are You include it in code file?) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll, it is a installer package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref, It is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App platform (you can see this dll in dependencies int your project)

Comment: You have no real choice but to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` for ASP.NET Core 3.0+. `UseEndpoints` _is_ in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` assembly, but that assembly is no longer deployed as a NuGet package. See [Framework reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) in the "Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0" guide for the specifics on referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in 3.0+.